# What is the frequency of witch huts in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm on a quest to find a witch hut in Vanilla Minecraft, in my usual world, with no mods.  I've traveled about 10K squares, and have found 3 relatively large swamp areas, and no witch hut.

I can find no information on the frequency of witch hunt generation.  Thoughts?

Also, I'm assuming witch hut's generate in peaceful and easy modes?  i.e. world generation is independent of difficulty setting?

Any thoughts on tools to use to identify witch huts in already generated areas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you generate the world with 'generate structures' on?

Comment: @JeffreyLin I generated the world 2+ years ago, so not sure, but assume so, as I have found one village in the world.

Comment: As far as I know the huts won't spawn in existing chunks. You'll need to find a swamp in a new chunk for it to have a chance of a Witch's hut.

Comment: @ChrisF my 10K walk was all on new chunks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AMIDST to check, though it isn't always accurate. Witch Huts appears as "Witch" with a dark icon.

They are independent of difficulty settings. They are generated when the chunk is generated, like biome features. They don't "spawn" dynamically.

If AMIDST shows them correctly, I've tried a few seeds which shows that Witch Huts are rarer than Desert+Jungle Temples and NPC Villages. I would say two times rarer.

---

A bit source digging (1.4.5) shows that they should be generated in the same way as Desert/Jungle Temples as a "Scattered Feature". The fact that AMIDST shows more "Temples" than "Witches" could be due to the fact that "Temples" includes both Desert and Jungle Temples on both desert and jungle biomes, while "Witch Huts" only generates on swampland biome.

Part of the relevant code in `StructureScatteredFeatureStart` and `ChunkProviderGenerate.populate`.

Comment: do you know how a "scattered feature" is stored in the data structures?   I'm curious, because I'm assuming the same mechanism for storing Witch spawn areas, and Wither Skeleton Spawn Areas is used....

Comment: @John I haven't found the code of spawning witches, so I have no idea.

Comment: @John Scattered structure features are stored the same way as other structures, so it's blocks-in-world + a separate database of bounding boxes that says "this 3D region is a [structure type]".

Answer (score 0):

Find another swamp area then use a map and the map might show a witch hut